# The symmetrization inequality

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking to prove the following: If $X$ is a real-valued RV such that its symmetrization ($X-X'$ with $X'$ an iid copy of $X$ defined on the same probability space) is $L^1$, then $X$ is actually $L^1$.  This would remove the additional hypothesis from the proof [here](https://math.uc.edu/~brycw/probab/charakt/charakt.pdf) of theorem 1.6.1 found on p.14.  I'm not too upset about the additional hypothesis just within the context of this theorem, but as far as I can see the author makes use of the stronger claim in the proof of theorem 2.5.2 p.29.  Please correct me if I'm mistaken.  He does not know anything about $X$ being integrable a priori there.

Comment: 123 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $N$ so that $P(|X| < N) > 0$.  Since $X$ and $X'$ are independent, 
$E[|X|] = E[|X| \; | \; |X'| < N]$.  But given $|X'| < N$, $|X| \le |X - X'| + |X'| < |X - X'| + N$. So $E[|X|\; |\; |X'| < N] \le E[|X - X'| \; | \; |X'| < N] + N < \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

More generally:

> Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and that $X+Y$ is integrable, then $X$ and $Y$ are both integrable (and, as everybody knows, the reverse implication always holds, even with no independence property).

To wit, Fubini theorem yields $E[|X+Y|]=E[u(Y)]$, where, for every $y$, $u(y)=E[|X+y|]$.

By hypothesis, $u(Y)$ is integrable hence *there exists at least one point $y$ such that $u(y)$ is finite*. Thus, $X+y$ is integrable, which implies that $X$ is integrable.